# Is there a way to disable to web view of an email after it has been sent

Tags: marketing-cloud

When an Exact Target email includes the "View Email as Web Page" link, is there a way to disable the auto-generated web page after an email has been sent so it can't be linked-to anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.

Long answer, you can talk to support to see if they have any way to 'take down' the page, but even if they do (Which I don't believe they do), this will lead to anyone clicking that link going to a 404 page.  This is a very bad user experience.  I am not sure why you would want to remove this after a send, as all it does is mimic the HTML email that they already have in their inbox.

I do believe there is an expiration time period on those VAWP pages, so after X amount of time (I believe it is 6 months) this will no longer link to a page.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I also talked to support and they told me they don't have a "take down" function.  

An email was sent from our org that contained slightly confidential info, and the powers that be weren't comfortable with the web-view page existing.  However the email is out in the world, and out of their control anyway.

Comment: well good news is that those pages are not searchable/indexable (if that is even a word...), so without the exact URL no one from outside can access them.  They may actually be even less of a security risk than the email itself.